# What's the noun for feigned?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

There's feint but I feel that doesn't quite have the same meaning (more for the physical). Disingenious(ness) is similar but again is different (more negative).

I'm looking for a word that describes an action and is neutral. Something like "He rolled his eyes but his smile betrayed it was a feint."

I'll accept feint as answer for now.

Comment: What exact meaning are you looking for? Would pretender suffice?

Comment: The meaning of feigned... just as a noun. So I could say something like "but he knew it was a <noun of feigned>".

Comment: How about ruse?

Comment: @Nimitz14 Please update the question with how it would be used. Are you looking to describe a person who feigns or an action that feigns? Also, you mention disengeniousness is too negattive but you don't mention if you're looking for a positive noun, a neutral noun, or just a less negative noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Feigned" is a participle, a verb form used as an adjective, where the base verb is "feign".  A verb does not necessarily have a corresponding noun, but in the case of "feign" the corresponding noun is indeed "feint", as you originally thought.  (See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feint for clarity; their definition of "feint" is literally "something feigned", though as you note it's primarily a physical combat term.)

So while feint is the exact noun form of feigned, it sounds like you're looking for a synonym with a different set of connotations.  Try "pretense" or "disguise", or update your question with the context you're using it in.

Answer (score 3):

A **sham**:

> something that is not what it purports to be; a spurious imitation; fraud or hoax. 
>   http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sham

Also, fabrication, counterfeit, fake.

Answer (score 1):

*Given the edits to the question*

> **dissimulation**
>   concealment of one's thoughts, feelings, or character; pretense. (Google)

He rolled his eyes, but his smile betrayed it was a **dissimulation**.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of *sham*, I suggest ***facade*** (or ***façade***):

> **[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facade)**:
>
>   a false, superficial, or artificial appearance or effect
>   - tried to preserve the *façade* of a happy marriage
>
> **[US English by Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/facade)**:
>
>   An outward appearance
>     that is maintained to conceal a less pleasant or creditable reality.
>   *‘her flawless public facade masked private despair’*
>
> **[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/facade)**:
>
>   A facade is an outward appearance which is deliberately false
>     and gives you a wrong impression about someone or something.
>   *They hid the troubles plaguing their marriage
>     behind a facade of family togetherness.*